# how do you replace an array with another array without deleting unmatch keys in first array?

Tags: php, arrays

Array1:

```
array('key01'=>321312, 'key03'=>23)
```

Array2:

```
array('key01'=>22, 'key04'=>78, 'key05'=>54)
```

I'm trying to to replace the values if array1 with the values of array2 and leaving any keys untouched that are not in array2.

So the outcome would be:

```
array('key01'=>22, 'key03'=>23, 'key04'=>78, 'key05'=>54)
```

Comment: you are not replacing then you are wanting to merge, use the `array_merge` like Barmar mentions.

Comment: Damn it. Why didn't I think of that :/

Comment: @Barmar, could you post it as an answer please!

Comment: http://php.net/array_merge? note example #3 on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_merge`:

```
$a1 = array('key01'=>321312, 'key03'=>23);
$a2 = array('key01'=>22, 'key04'=>78, 'key05'=>54);
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = $arr2 + $arr1;
```

The keys will remain as you said:

```
$arr1 = array('key01'=>22, 'key04'=>78, 'key05'=>54, 'key03'=>23);
```

But the order is important. In the case above, $arr2, being first, will overwrite values with the same key of $arr1.